# Lightswitch html client override default save button

Tags: html, client, visual-studio-lightswitch

I want to be able to override the default save button on the html client however i cant seem to find the control to do so. I want to write some validation behind it and allow the user to select an option but I just cant seem to find it.

I know the silverlight client you can override it but just cant seem to override it in the html client.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's achieved using beforeApplyChanges.

example: (Please excuse any typos/syntax errors, you get the rough idea!)

```
myapp.AddEditScreen.beforeApplyChanges = function (screen) {
    switch (screen.Property_SavingStatus) {
    case 'Not Saving':
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Override Save -> toggle SavingStatus -> Call Save again
            SaveMyChangesMyWay();
            screen.Property_SavingStatus = 'Commit';
            myapp.commitChanges(); // Or Discard or Apply.
        }, 500);
        return false; // Cancel save changes request
        break;
    case 'Apply':
        return true;
        break;
    default:
};
```

Comment: thank kris mate, I was using before apply changes with a yesNo option however it would save before any input.

Comment: if (screen.Job.Status.DisplayOrder < 4) {
        msls.showMessageBox("Job has not started yet would you like to commence the job?",
      { title: "Warning!", buttons: msls.MessageBoxButtons.yesNo }).then(function (response) {
          switch (response) {
              case msls.MessageBoxResult.yes:
                  myapp.FinishJob_execute();
        
                  
                  break;
              case msls.MessageBoxResult.no:
              default:
                  break;
          }
      });
    }
    else {
        msls.showMessageBox("Job Saved successfully");
  
    }

Comment: Did you notice the 'return true;' and 'return false;' line?  Did you also notice the saving status flag or the switch statement?  Essentially it's all about controlling program flow. When you return false it cancels the save request.  If you don't return anything or return true it allows the save to commence.

Comment: +1 Voted. You have no idea how much this answer has helped me debug a problem instantly that I'd wasted the previous 24 hours on. Thanks Kris!

Comment: Ok Ive decided to take a different approach to this and changed my screen behaviour to browse.

Comment: my case "YES" does not do anything. switch (response) {
                 case msls.showMessageBox.yes:
                     myapp.commitChanges();
                    
                     break;
                 case msls.MessageBoxResult.no:
                     myapp.commitChanges();

                 default:
                     break;
             }

Comment: @paulpitchford Glad it helped champ.