# Lightswitch HTML - prevent unsaved changes dialogue appearing

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I currently have a view screen called Order, and on this screen there is a table called OrderLine. this contains x amount of data in regards to that particular order. I have added a custom button which will update the row one by one in terms of marking them all as recieved. this however causes the unsaved changes dialog to appear when navigating away if not saved, there is going to be times where a user will not do this and if they do hit the save button, then all my custom validation is missed and none of the syntax is ran. **is there a way to disable it?** it does not matter if this is for the entire application either.. **if I could re-direct this save changes to a specific button on screen that would be equally as good**.

this is on a view screen, not add/edit screen so I cannot simply disable the buttons like I have done on these unfortunately.

[image]

any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

a temporary fix I am using for this is using the `myapp.applyChanges()`; but this has a small delay each time, of less than a second, but its not as slick as I would like

Answer (score 0):

myapp.applyChanges on each call of your button seems like the right approach. A delay seems normal, as it involved committing the change to the server. What kind of behavior would you expect for this to be considered slick?

If you wish to override the save functionality, you can use the process detailed in [Lightswitch html client override default save button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780203/lightswitch-html-client-override-default-save-button)